How Spanning tree (RSTP) will work in the below case
I have New 2xDELL Switches in VLT Domain connected to old 2xDELL Switches in another VLT Domain and the link between these switches should carry vLAN 5
However , vLANs 2,3,4 should be tagged on the links between DELL Switches and Cisco Core Switches
If I have RSTP Enabled on all Switches , will one of the links be blocked by RSTP and what would be the alternative ? Should RVSTP enabled on DELL Switches to mitigate this scenario ?



If I have RSTP Enabled on all Switches , will one of the links be blocked by RSTP

Yes - each VLT domain acts like a single switch, and multiple connections between two switches create a loop - when you're ignoring VLAN connectivity. Since there is no actual loop on the VLAN level, xSTP isn't required to block one of the links.
Since RSTP is completely VLAN agnostic, it does block one link all the same, and you're losing VLAN connectivity across the blocked link.

and what would be the alternative ?

Depends on what you actually want to achieve - running just VLAN 5 between the VLT domains doesn't make too much sense to me.

Should RVSTP enabled on DELL Switches to mitigate this scenario ?

Yes. Cisco's RPVST+ has the advantage of creating a separate spanning tree for each VLAN. That way it automatically detects that there's no VLAN-level loop and doesn't block anything. An alternative would be IEEE MSTP with two instances.

The network doesn't have VLANs with redundant-links from the get go. Running per-vlan RPVST+ wouldn't hurt.
